# shift/reduce conflict in grammar with optional semicolon

Tags: bison, yacc

[Sample repository](https://github.com/iluuu1994/php-match-yacc-test)

I'd like to do something like this:

```php
// match used as a statement, semicolon is optional
match (1) {}

// match used as an expression, semicolon is required
1 + match (2) {};
```

```
statement
    : expression_without_block T_SEMICOLON
    | expression_with_block
;

expression
    : expression_without_block
    | expression_with_block
;

expression_without_block
    : scalar
    | expression_without_block T_PLUS expression
    | T_PLUS expression
;

expression_with_block
    : T_MATCH T_LEFT expression T_RIGHT T_CURLY_LEFT T_CURLY_RIGHT
;
```

The idea is that `expression_with_block` can't be used at the beginning of a statement, making the following unambiguous:

```php
match (1) {}
+2;

// Can't mean
(match (1) {} + 2);
// because of the line "expression_without_block T_PLUS expression"
```

The grammar causes a shift/reduce conflicts but I have no idea why. The output says the following (but I'm not sure what to do with it):

```
State 11 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

...

State 11

    5 expression: expression_without_block .
    8 expression_without_block: expression_without_block . T_PLUS expression

    T_PLUS  shift, and go to state 14

    T_PLUS    [reduce using rule 5 (expression)]
    $default  reduce using rule 5 (expression)
```

[The full output file can be found here](https://github.com/iluuu1994/php-match-yacc-test/blob/master/php.output).

I'm also not even sure this is the right approach because then something like this wouldn't work:

```php
// `match` can't be at the lhs of an expression, even in sub-expressions
func_call(match (10) {} + 20);
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm describing here in bison? I'm not a bison expert so I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I understand how the grammatical restriction you propose implements the requirement. I presume your intention is to (mostly) allow semicolons at the end of statements to be optional (as in Javascript or Awk) but that's much more complicated than it looks at first sight. Anyway, I don't think the solution here has to do with semicolons. Or match expressions, for that matter. The basic problem is that if you allow statement expressions to start with unary operators (or with parenthetic expressions), then you create ambiguity if the previous statement was an expression...

Comment: One way to resolve this issue is to disallow (possibly) unary or (possibly) postfix operators to follow a newline. See, for example, Javascript's ban on `expr<NL>++`. There are many other possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very classic kind of conflict that happen with left recursive rules, but as the default resolution of a shift/reduce conflict is to do a shift, then 
everything will be fine here.

Here is how you should read the bison trace:

```
T_PLUS  shift, and go to state 14              -- when next token is T_PLUS shift action is selected

T_PLUS    [reduce using rule 5 (expression)]   -- the action between [] was disabled by Bison default conflict resolution
```

To override Bison's default conflict resolution (which is not necessary here), we may use operator precedence (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Precedence-Decl) or precedence for non operator (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Non-Operators)

Comment: Your comment was tremendously useful, thank you! It turns out my example did not perfectly reproduce the issue. In the real repo it's actually a reduce/reduce conflict. https://gist.github.com/iluuu1994/b1135190b12af564b22cb05845bff010#file-y-output-L4701 Apparently it's a conflict between the infix and binary `+`/`-` operators. I'm still not sure why exactly it's happening. But I'm accepting your answer as you did perfectly answer my original question.

Comment: Welcome. Your grammar is ambiguous because `+<expr_with_block>+<expr>` can be derived in 2 valid syntax trees: `(+<expr_with_block>)(+ <expr>)` and `(+<expr_with_block>+<expr>)`. Then we cannot decide between the 2 reduce actions. I am afraid you will have to put a trailing semicolon at the end of all of your expressions. I can detail my answer in a new post if you need.

Comment: I found a very suboptimal way to implement it: https://github.com/iluuu1994/php-src/commit/98a49968eacf0cfe29ebaed3493aa17ebf74031b I had to duplicate a huge block, I'll see if I can get rid of the duplication. Thanks again for your help!